# How to delete a complete directory tree as quick as possible? Python

Tags: python, filesystems, directory

This is what I do but takes forever:

```
>>> import shutil,os
>>> for d in os.listdir("."):
...     if os.path.isdir(d):
...         shutil.rmtree(d)
```

Directories are full of files in the order of several thousands files.

What is the fastest way to do it instead?

Comment: That is limted by the OS, and shutilrmtree is as fast as you can go. It may be that calling a native OS call for rmtree may be faster. What system are you using? We can pull a ctypes call for that, and you check if its faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately that's FS speed-bound. There's no real way to speed it up if directories are filled up with many files.

Comment: but how files are stored in the directory then? are they all in consecutive memory blocks? I was thinking maybe there is a way to delete 'em all as if they were on a single huge file. I might just be lacking some knowledge about filesystems...

Comment: well, if we're talking about a unix filesystem, each file is associated with an inode and deleting a file is practically unlinking it from the underlaying inode. that process takes some time, unfortunately. there's no guarantee that inode allocation will be consecutive.